# Using dotConnect with MVC5 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, razor

I have an existing SQLServer based MVC 5 Razor project. Our deployment site does not allow SQLServer, must be Oracle. I have the devArt dotConnect Oracle provider, but I cannot figure out how to migrate to it. Is there a COMPLETE  list of required references to add and web.config modifications ? Also, I am using Identity Framework, I have noticed a number of dll's and sql files scattered about the devart installation folder, do any of these need to be included as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial from company; it was very clear and easy to follow.

Using Entity Framework Implementation of ASP.NET Identity for Oracle http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Identity-Tutorial-Entity.html

I needed to make sure the dll's were set to copy local, once they were the server deployment worked without any installs or modifications to the server.